# Creation of an Objective-C image array which outputs as a jpeg

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, image, image-processing

I am trying to create a way of taking an array of photos and outputting them as a photo collage in a single jpeg format.

Something like the image at the following link: 
http://www.fanpop.com/clubs/the-simpsons/images/10494119/title/simpsons-collage-photo

I am pretty new to Objective-C so any ideas you have would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You could use a UICollectionView and load each image into an image view. What have you got/tried so far?

Comment: You could use CoreGraphics or CoreAnimation. or place it in subviews next to each other and get the image context. …

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use CoreGraphics.

For example:

```
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
  [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)]; // this line is for every image you draw in the collage.

  UIImage *finalImage =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); // this is your final image of the collage.

  // Now we creating the jpeg file
  NSData *jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(finalImage, 1.0);
  [jpegData writeToFile:filepath atomically:YES];

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Of course, this is only an example, but thats the direction